# Deallocation of Dynamic Arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

Here's the code I am working with...

```
while(temp[i]!=0){
    while(temp[i]!=3){
        FrameBuffer[a]=temp[i];
        i++;
        a++;
    }
    FrameBuffer[a]=temp[i];
    printf(" Framebuffer: %s ", FrameBuffer);
    result=layer1(FrameBuffer,PacketAction);
    i++;
    a=0;
}
```

The problem is that I want FrameBuffer to be reset each time it goes through the inner while loop (Size of FrameBuffer is 0 at start of loop). I've tried using free(FrameBuffer) but I get an error because I free the array more than once. I also tried writing FrameBuffer=NULL, but that did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please show more, especially how you declare `FrameBuffer`.

Comment: Also, you can not use it as a string unless you add the string terminator character `'\0'`.

Comment: I declare it as...


char *FrameBuffer=calloc(2048,sizeof(char));

Comment: If it really just holds a null-terminated string then you don't need to free it or clear it, just write `'\0'` to the final byte. I'm afraid you are making us guess at what you mean by *"reset".*

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I am confused about the term 'null-terminated string'. Pretty much the first iteration of the while loop goes through 99 times, and the second iteration will go through 98 times. FrameBuffer[0]-FrameBuffer[97] will be overwritten which I want. But that FrameBuffer[98] would have the same contents from the first iteration. I want it so that there is nothing in FrameBuffer after each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to initialise FrameBuffer before the start of each inner loop, `memset` can be used-:

```
while(temp[i]!=0) {
    memset(FrameBuffer, 0, sizeof(FrameBuffer));

    while(temp[i]!=3) {
```

Comment: Hmm I tried that, but it still doesn't empty out the contents of FrameBuffer.

Comment: I've tested the code and it works. Are you sure the printf statement or whatever is used to check the contents of FrameBuffer is at the correct place in the code?

Comment: So memset did the trick. The only thing that didn't work was the "sizeof(FrameBuffer)", but when I changed it to StrLen it did work. Thank you guys so much for the help. It's always nice when I learn about a new keyword in C.

Comment: `memset()` is a function, not a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show the declarations or give a particularly good description of the input string, `temp`, it is a bit hard to know what you're up to.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int somefunc(const char *fb, int pa);
extern int layer1(const char *fb, int pa);

int somefunc(const char *temp, int PacketAction)
{
    int rc = 0;
    char *FrameBuffer = calloc(2048, sizeof(char));
    if (FrameBuffer != 0)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (temp[i] != '\0')
        {
            int a = 0;
            while (temp[i] != 3)
                FrameBuffer[a++] = temp[i++];
            FrameBuffer[a++] = temp[i++];
            FrameBuffer[a] = '\0';
            assert(a < 2048);
            printf("Framebuffer: %.*s\n", a, FrameBuffer);
            int result = layer1(FrameBuffer, PacketAction);
            if (rc == 0)
                rc = result;
        }
    }
    return rc;
}
```

This is probably sufficient.  The function `layer1` gets a null terminated string in `FrameBuffer` (it has no other visible way of determining how long the data is).

Note that by declaring `a` in the scope of the outer loop, I don't need to reinitialize it at the end of the loop.  I've used `a++` and `i++` to increment the counters; it allows for compact notation with no loss of readability to the experienced C programmer — though I concede it can be a little more difficult for novice programmers to handle.  Nevertheless, the idiom is worth learning.

I wonder if the inner loop should check for `'\0'` as well as 3 (aka `'\3'` or `'\003'`); I would need to know whether nulls can ever appear in `temp` other than at the very end.  The code shown takes a lazy way out of validating for no overflow of the `FrameBuffer`.  It would be better still if the function was told the length of the input `temp`:

```
void somefunc(const char *temp, size_t templen, int PacketAction)
```

The code could be written more resiliently.  It could probably use `strlen(temp)`, but it isn't absolutely clear from the available information.